# Optimizing query using joins in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

I have a query I would like to optimize, It takes 29 seconds to complete. I have tried creating a view of the union join but gives worse result.

```
 select o.orderno, o.orderdate, c.lastname 
from orders o 
join (select 
    `hdb`.`contacts`.`CONTACTID` AS `CONTACTID`, 
    `hdb`.`contacts`.`LASTNAME` AS `LASTNAME`
    from `hdb`.`contacts` 
    union 
select 
    `sugarcrm`.`contacts`.`id` AS `CONTACTID`,
    `sugarcrm`.`contacts`.`last_name` AS `LASTNAME`
    from `sugarcrm`.`contacts` ) c on c.CONTACTID = o.CONTACTID  


order by orderno desc
limit 0,100000000
```

Under the mysql slow query log i get the following part:

```
select 
        `hdb`.`contacts`.`CONTACTID` AS `CONTACTID`, 
        `hdb`.`contacts`.`CLIENTID` AS `CLIENTID`, 
         concat(`hdb`.`contacts`.`FIRSTNAME`,_utf8' ',coalesce(`hdb`.`contacts`.`INITIALS`,_utf8'')) AS `FIRSTNAME`, 
        `hdb`.`contacts`.`LASTNAME` AS `LASTNAME`, 
        `hdb`.`contacts`.`PHONE` AS `PHONE`, 
        `hdb`.`contacts`.`FAX` AS `FAX`, 
        `hdb`.`contacts`.`DEPARTMENT` AS `DEPARTMENT`, 
        `hdb`.`contacts`.`TITLE` AS `TITLE`, 
        `hdb`.`contacts`.`INFO` AS `INFO`, 
        `hdb`.`contacts`.`SALUTATION` AS `SALUTATION`, 
        `hdb`.`contacts`.`EMAIL` AS `EMAIL`,    
        CASE 
            WHEN `hdb`.`contacts`.`ACTIVE` != 0 THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END DELETED,        
        'paradox' AS `SOURCEDATABASE`
        from `hdb`.`contacts` 
        union 
    select 
        `sugarcrm`.`contacts`.`id` AS `CONTACTID`,
        `sugarcrm`.`accounts_contacts`.`account_id` AS `CLIENTID`,
        `sugarcrm`.`contacts`.`first_name` AS `FIRSTNAME`,
        `sugarcrm`.`contacts`.`last_name` AS `LASTNAME`,
        `sugarcrm`.`contacts`.`phone_work` AS `PHONE`,
        `sugarcrm`.`contacts`.`phone_fax` AS `FAX`,
        `sugarcrm`.`contacts`.`department` AS `department`,
        `sugarcrm`.`contacts`.`title` AS `title`,
        `sugarcrm`.`contacts`.`description` AS `INFO`,
        `sugarcrm`.`contacts`.`salutation` AS `salutation`,
        `sugarcrm`.`email_addresses`.`email_address` AS `Email`,            
        `sugarcrm`.`contacts`.`deleted` AS DELETED,
        'sugar' AS `SOURCEDATABASE` 
        from (((`sugarcrm`.`contacts` 
        left join `sugarcrm`.`email_addr_bean_rel` 
        on((`sugarcrm`.`contacts`.`id` = `sugarcrm`.`email_addr_bean_rel`.`bean_id`))) 
        left join `sugarcrm`.`accounts_contacts` 
        on((`sugarcrm`.`contacts`.`id` = `sugarcrm`.`accounts_contacts`.`contact_id`))) 
        join `sugarcrm`.`email_addresses` 
        on((`sugarcrm`.`email_addr_bean_rel`.`email_address_id` = `sugarcrm`.`email_addresses`.`id`)))
```

But this runs quickly if run on its own. Using explain gives me the following.

```
1, PRIMARY, o, ALL, , , , , 6085, Using temporary; Using filesort
1, PRIMARY, <derived2>, ALL, , , , , 18877, Using where
2, DERIVED, contacts, ALL, , , , , 8009, 
3, UNION, contacts, ALL, , , , , 10251, 
, UNION RESULT, <union2,3>, ALL, , , , , ,
```

Comment: I'm quite sure 90% of the queries you've posted are irrelevant tinge question. Please edit your queries given to the absolute minimum code that demonstrates the problem. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), preferably on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) so we can code against something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your top query, I would alter it to a double left-join to each respective table of contacts... That said, it appears a customer's contact ID should be in EITHER of them (unless you have other contact tables).  That said, the left-join will be quicker than doing a prequery / join.  For the name, I would case/when... if the one table doesn't have a match (via IS NULL), then use the name from the other table and vice-versa... if it DOES have a value, use it.  Then, just make sure your order table has an index on the order number.

```
select 
      o.orderno, 
      o.orderdate, 
      CASE when hc.contactid is null 
           then sc.last_name else hc.lastname end as LastName
   from 
      orders o 
         LEFT JOIN hdb.contacts hc
            ON o.ContactID = hc.ContactID
         LEFT JOIN sugarcrm.contacts sc
            ON o.ContactID = sc.id
   order by 
      orderno desc
   limit 0, 100000000
```

If you DO have other tables of contacts, but only care about those associated with the "hc" and "sc" aliased tables, I would add a WHERE clause for

```
WHERE hc.contactID IS NOT NULL
   OR sc.id IS NOT NULL
```

to ensure at least ONE of the tables DOES have a match.

Comment: can you help me with this one [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062994/optimizing-a-query-using-union-left-joins-and-inner-joins]