# sugarcrm simple query not working

Tags: mysql, sugarcrm

I am trying to retrieve the name of the compnay a contact belongs to. the relation ships exists in the table `account_contacts`, how ever when I try to tun the query it barks

```
SELECT
    accounts.`name`,
    contacts.first_name
FROM
    contacts,
    accounts
INNER JOIN accounts_contacts ON contacts.id = accounts_contacts.contact_id
AND accounts.id = accounts_contacts.account_id
```

error i get is

```
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'contacts.id' in 'on clause'
```

AFTER changes:

```
SELECT
accounts.`name`,
contacts.first_name,
accounts.id
FROM
    contacts
INNER JOIN accounts_contacts ON contacts.id = accounts_contacts.contact_id
JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = accounts_contacts.account_id
WHERE first_name = 'shamraiz'
```

your query returns 2 rows with the results i expect. the account id are different. However the query I have redone again implementing it your way does not work. the accountid is the same, but returns 2 rows.

```
SELECT
    contacts.id AS CONTACTID,
    accounts.id AS ACCOUNTID,
    contacts.first_name,
    contacts.last_name,
    contacts.phone_work,
    contacts.phone_fax,
    contacts.department,
    contacts.title,
    contacts.description,
    contacts.salutation,
    email_addresses.email_address,
    contacts.deleted
FROM
    contacts
INNER JOIN accounts_contacts ON contacts.id = accounts_contacts.contact_id
    JOIN accounts on accounts.id = accounts_contacts.account_id
INNER JOIN email_addr_bean_rel ON contacts.id = email_addr_bean_rel.bean_id
INNER JOIN email_addresses ON email_addresses.id = email_addr_bean_rel.email_address_id

where first_name = 'shamraiz'
```

the next query returns 3 rows, but the top 2 are dupplicated

```
SELECT
    contacts.id AS CONTACTID,
    accounts.id AS ACCOUNTID,
    contacts.first_name,
    contacts.last_name,
    contacts.phone_work,
    contacts.phone_fax,
    contacts.department,
    contacts.title,
    contacts.description,
    contacts.salutation,
    email_addresses.email_address,
    contacts.deleted
FROM
    contacts
inner JOIN accounts_contacts ON contacts.id = accounts_contacts.contact_id
    left JOIN accounts on accounts.id = accounts_contacts.account_id
left JOIN email_addr_bean_rel ON contacts.id = email_addr_bean_rel.bean_id
left JOIN email_addresses ON email_addresses.id = email_addr_bean_rel.email_address_id
where first_name = 'shamraiz'
```

**from contacts**

`SELECT * FROM`sugarcrm`.`contacts`where first_name = 'shamraiz'` returns 2 rows

**from account_contact relation**

`SELECT * FROM`sugarcrm`.`accounts_contacts`where contact_id = '17619b5e-db07-fa3b-6748-51a73ef38c5e'` returns 1 row

`SELECT * FROM`sugarcrm`.`accounts_contacts`where contact_id = '003b0000006ZMDXAA4'` returns 1 row.

So the final query should return 2 different rows as they are two contacts with similar names joined to 2 different companies.

A contact can belong to 1 company.

**more adjustments:**

I have made some amendments but it is returning 1 record. should return 2. I need it to pull out the record whether or not a relationship exists for email address.

```
SELECT
    contacts.id AS CONTACTID,
    accounts.id AS ACCOUNTID,
    contacts.first_name,
    contacts.last_name,
    contacts.phone_work,
    contacts.phone_fax,
    contacts.department,
    contacts.title,
    contacts.description,
    contacts.salutation,
    EM.email_address,
    contacts.deleted,
    EABR.primary_address
FROM
    contacts
LEFT JOIN accounts_contacts ON contacts.id = accounts_contacts.contact_id
JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = accounts_contacts.account_id
LEFT JOIN email_addr_bean_rel EABR ON contacts.id = EABR.bean_id
AND (
    EABR.primary_address = 1
    || (EABR.primary_address IS NOT NULL AND EABR.primary_address != 0)
) 
JOIN email_addresses EM ON EABR.email_address_id = EM.id
WHERE
    contacts.first_name = 'shamraiz'
```

**resolved answer:**

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `view_contacts_sugar_hdb`
AS
select
    `hdb`.`contacts`.`CONTACTID` AS `CONTACTID`,
    `hdb`.`contacts`.`CLIENTID` AS `CLIENTID`,
     concat(`hdb`.`contacts`.`FIRSTNAME`,_utf8' ',coalesce(`hdb`.`contacts`.`INITIALS`,_utf8'')) AS `FIRSTNAME`,
    `hdb`.`contacts`.`LASTNAME` AS `LASTNAME`,
    `hdb`.`contacts`.`PHONE` AS `PHONE`,
    `hdb`.`contacts`.`FAX` AS `FAX`,
    `hdb`.`contacts`.`DEPARTMENT` AS `DEPARTMENT`,
    `hdb`.`contacts`.`TITLE` AS `TITLE`,
    `hdb`.`contacts`.`INFO` AS `INFO`,
    `hdb`.`contacts`.`SALUTATION` AS `SALUTATION`,
    `hdb`.`contacts`.`EMAIL` AS `EMAIL`,
    CASE
        WHEN `hdb`.`contacts`.`ACTIVE` != 0 THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END DELETED,
    'paradox' AS `SOURCEDATABASE`
    from `hdb`.`contacts`
    union
        SELECT
        contacts.id AS CONTACTID,
        accounts_contacts.account_id AS CLIENTID,
        contacts.first_name AS FIRSTNAME,
        contacts.last_name AS LASTNAME,
        contacts.phone_work AS PHONE,
        contacts.phone_fax AS FAX,
        contacts.department AS DEPARTMENT,
        contacts.title AS TITLE,
        contacts.description AS INFO,
        contacts.salutation AS SALUTATION,
        email_addresses.email_address AS EMAIL,
        contacts.deleted AS DELETED,
        'sugar' AS SOURCEDATABASE
    FROM
        (
            (
                (
                    sugarcrm.contacts
                    LEFT JOIN sugarcrm.email_addr_bean_rel ON (
                        (
                            contacts.id = email_addr_bean_rel.bean_id
                        )
                    )
                    AND (
                        email_addr_bean_rel.primary_address = 1 || (
                            email_addr_bean_rel.primary_address IS NOT NULL
                            AND email_addr_bean_rel.primary_address != 0
                        )
                    )
                )
                LEFT JOIN sugarcrm.accounts_contacts ON (
                    (
                        contacts.id = accounts_contacts.contact_id
                    )
                )
            )
            JOIN sugarcrm.email_addresses ON (
                (
                    email_addr_bean_rel.email_address_id = email_addresses.id
                )
            )
        )
    LEFT JOIN sugarcrm.accounts ON accounts.id = accounts_contacts.account_id
ORDER BY
    `LASTNAME`,
    `FIRSTNAME`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
       contacts.id AS CONTACTID,
       accounts.id AS ACCOUNTID,
       contacts.first_name,
       contacts.last_name,
       contacts.phone_work,
       contacts.phone_fax,
       contacts.department,
       contacts.title,
       contacts.description,
       contacts.salutation,
       email_addresses.email_address,
       contacts.deleted
   FROM
      contacts
         INNER JOIN accounts_contacts 
            ON contacts.id = accounts_contacts.contact_id
            JOIN accounts
               ON accounts.id = accounts_contacts.account_id
         INNER JOIN email_addr_bean_rel EABR
            ON contacts.id = EABR.bean_id
            INNER JOIN email_addresses EM
               ON EABR.email_address_id = EM.id
   WHERE 
      contacts.first_name = 'shamraiz'
```

Just like the other questions I've helped you on...

List one table at a time, INNER JOIN (or LEFT JOIN) to the next table "ON" whatever criteria that those two tables relate... Then, INNER JOIN (or LEFT JOIN) to the next table in the relationship hierarchy.

If you have multiple contact records for the same person, such as different accounts and/or emails, you WILL get multiple records.

Comment: this not returning required results. your 1st query you posted did, but I need the other data from for email address which requires joins. This query returning duplicated row. I have updated my question

Comment: can you help me with this please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152866/optimizing-a-union-join-inside-select-statement-of-other-joins

Answer (score 2):

If you use the SugarCRM framework and you know the id of the contact you are looking for. You can avoid all of the SQL.

```
$contact = BeanFactory::getBean('Contacts', $id);
$contact->account_name;
```

Want all contacts?

```
$contact = BeanFactory::getBean('Contacts');
$all = $contact->get_full_list();
foreach ($all as $contact) {
  echo "{$contact->name} {$contact->account_name} \n <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use an `INNER JOIN` query and use alias for tables

```
SELECT a.`name`, c.first_name
FROM contacts c
INNER JOIN accounts_contacts ac
ON c.id = ac.contact_id
INNER JOIN accounts a
ON ac.contact_id = a.id
```

Prepending the given alias to all the column will make database understand what table are them from while executing the query.